# No PING response from host but detecting IP address

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet, ping

I am using a 3G USB device (PTCL EVO Nitro) to connect to the Internet on Windows 8.

When I tried to open yahoo.com in IE, FF, and Chrome, none of the browsers display the page.  When I try to ping this host (www.yahoo.com), ping resolves the IP address but gives "Request timed out."

Is this problem with my ISP?? I called the ISP and they said that this issue is not at their end.

Following is a snapshot of the `ping` request. Please tell me how to fix this issue.

*** On a wireless Internet connection (with some other ISP), everything works fine.

[image: PING Response]

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, I am able to ping both the name and IP and get a reply.

It could be that one of the hops on the path from you to Yahoo is down.  This possibly means one of the routers between you and the destination (Yahoo) is down, or a network connection is severed, or a multitude of other possibilities.

If you are still having an issue, use traceroute to see of you are able to reach the host

```
tracert yahoo.com
```

That should tell you if the destination is reachable from your location.  Ping is not a reliable method, as ping is often disabled as a security measure.

This is a good beginner's [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/134132/how-to-use-traceroute-to-identify-network-problems/) on traceroute and how it work and what the info means.

Comment: From 11th hop and onward till 30th hop tracert command gives me Timeout. It means that there is something wrong with the ISP... Although this problem is automatically fixed now. It was the ISP's fault.